# Linear maps of polynomials, the bases of the space and their corresponding matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Suppose $T \in \mathrm{Hom}(\mathscr{P}_3(\mathbb{R}),\mathscr{P}_4(\mathbb{R}))$ is defined by:

$$Tp(x)=(x^2p(x))',$$

for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $S \in\mathrm{Hom} (\mathscr{P}_4(\mathbb{R}),\mathscr{P}_3(\mathbb{R}))$ is defined by:

$$Sp(x)=xp''(x),$$

for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $(1,x,x^2,x^3)$ be a basis for $\mathscr{P}_3(\mathbb{R})$ and $(1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4)$ be a basis for $\mathscr{P}_4(\mathbb{R})$. Find $ST$ and $\mathscr{M}(ST)$ (i.e. the matrix for ST).

I could use some help in solving this problem. I have tried a number of things which all seem to lead me nowhere. I understand that the linear map will operate on $p(x)$ but how do I incorporate the respective basis of the space? and were do I go from there?

Comment: Can you find $M(S)$ and $M(T)$? Then $M(ST)=M(S)M(T)$.

Comment: As for finding $ST$, what is $S(Tp)$? $Tp=2xp+x^2p'$, so $S(Tp)=x(2xp+x^2p')''=x(2p+2xp'+2xp'+x^2p'')'$, that is $S(Tp)=x(2p'+2p'+2xp''+2xp''+2p'+2xp''+x^2p''')$, in other words $S(Tp)=x(6p'+6xp''+x^2p'')=2xp'+6x^2p''+x^3p''$. (broke the passages to avoid the comment overflowing the margin.)

Comment: I understand up to the last line where you go from $S(Tp)=x(6p'+6xp''+x^2p'')$ to $S(Tp)=2xp'+6x^2p''+x^3p''$. Did you mean $S(Tp)=6xp'+6x^2p''+x^3p''$ or am I missing something?

Comment: You're right, that's a typo. And that last term should have $p'''$, not $p''$, btw.

Comment: That's a typo on my end! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Ddbb1994 : I know quite well linear operators but your question is still very hard to read for me, so please make more efforts, read others questions to see how they are written and see how yours is weird.

Comment: @Dbb that's a typo on my end too: I lost a prine in one of the passages :).

Comment: And @user1952009 I agree that the notation $(V,W)$ for linear maps from $V$ to $W$ is a bit strange, I'd write $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$, but that doesn't seem to make the question that hard to read...

Comment: Is it better now @user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $ST$ is just the composition of the two transformations, so you can find an expression for it by substituting the the value $Tp$ for $p$ in the expression for $Sp$.

As for finding its matrix, there are a couple of ways you could proceed. If you simplify the expression that you got for $S(Tp)$, then you can pretty much read it off from the coefficients of the result of applying this map to a generic third-degree polynomial. Remember that each column of the matrix will be the image of the corresponding basis vector. For example, if $ST(a+bx+cx^2+dx^3)=5ax^2+10bx^3$ (I’m just making up numbers here), then the matrix would be $$
\pmatrix{0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\5&0&0&0\\0&10&0&0},
$$ which you can see by setting each coefficient in the generic polynomial to $1$ in turn while setting the rest to zero.
Another way is to work out the individual matrices for $S$ and $T$ and multiply them. It’s worth doing it both ways to check your work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have another question if you don't mind. I have worked out both the product of $\mathscr{M}(S)* \mathscr{M}(T)$ and $\mathscr{M}(ST)$ by applying to a generic 3rd degree polynomial. Numerically these matrices are different however their reduced row echelon form for is the same? Have done the calculations correctly? Sorry if this is a stupid question its been a while since I haven'tworked with matrices.

Comment: @Ddbb1994 You should’ve ended up with the same matrix both ways. $\mathscr{M}(S)$ and $\mathscr{M}(T)$ aren’t square matrices, but their product will be $4\times4$. Most likely you made an algebraic error in expanding and simplifying the expressions for $S$ and $T$. Remember to start with a 4th-degree polynomial for $\mathscr{M}(S)$.

Answer (score 1):

$STp=(x^2(xp''(x)))'=(x^3p''(x))'$

Computing it for the generic polinomial in $\mathscr{P_4}(\mathbb{R})$
$ST(c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+c_3x^3+c_4x^4)=c_2x^2+c_3x^3+c_4x^4$, where $c_i\in\mathbb{R}, i=0, 1, 2, 3, 4$

Having chosen $(1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4)$ for the ordered base in $\mathscr{P_4}$, you get

$\mathscr{M}(ST)=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Of course I computed $TS$ not $ST$. Thanks to MickG, for the correct answer.